# Units in MathJax markup

Tags: discussion, mathjax

https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/31762/885

So what's the right way to put units inside of TeX blocks?  I remember a font directive but not what the word was. And it's a kludge anyway — was a proper unit macro notation ever added?

Answer (score 2):

#### Use `\text{}`.

This MathJaX code:

```
1 \times 10^{23} kg
```

produces this output:

> $ 1 \times 10^{23} kg $

By wrapping the `kg` in `\text{ }`, we get:

```
1 \times 10^{23} \text{ kg}
```

which produces

> $ 1 \times 10^{23} \text{ kg} $

Comment: So what's the difference between mathrm and text? The latter might have a better chance of being remembered anyway.

Comment: @JDługosz the only difference I've found is that mathrm strips spaces, text doesn't.

Comment: So the tilde on the outside lets $\TeX$ decide the right amount of space, while a space inside of `text` forces it to be an actual space character in that font.

Comment: You can also use something like `1 \times 10^{23} ~ \text{kg}`: $ 1 \times 10^{23} ~ \text{kg} $